# ZF2 : If tutorial changes must be done in newer projects

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-db

This question may look like opinion based, But I am very confused and also did not found any resource clarifying, So just hope any body here better idea.

I have worked on ZF2 Projects during its Beta releases and work till First stable release. I followed Skeleton application guidelines to build Project structure/code (Models, Form and Controllers). Then After 2 yrs gap, Now I got one more ZF2 Project (ZF2 Library 2.2 version), and I developed this by copied my older projects source code files. Project working now.

But as I checkout newer version of Skeleton application, I am confused, Here skeleton and lot of changes then previous one. I did not know If they are for better, mandatory or just over-engineered.

Some differences are :

**In ZF2 2.0**

Form Validator worked like that.

```
if (!$this->inputFilter) {
   $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

   $inputFilter->add(array(
     'name'     => 'user_id',
     'required' => true,
     'filters'  => array(
         array('name' => 'StripTags'),
         array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
     ),
     'validators' => array(
            ------
   )));
}
```

**While in ZF2 2.2**

```
if (!$this->inputFilter) {
    $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
    $factory     = new InputFactory();

    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name'     => 'artist',
        'required' => true,
        'filters'  => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            ---------
        ),
    )));
```

**In ZF2 2.0**

DB Models worked like that.

In Module.php

```
return array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Test\Model\UserTable' =>  function($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $table = new Model\UserTable($dbAdapter);
            return $table;
        },
    ),
);
```

In Models constructor

```
public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
    $this->initialize();
}
```

And Models query like that

```
$rowset = $this->select(array('id' => $id));
```

**While in ZF2 2.2**

In Module.php

```
'Application\Model\UserTable' =>  function($sm) {
     $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
     $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
     return $table;
},
'VarietyTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
     return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
 },
```

No need of Models constructor settings

Models query like that

```
$rowset = $this->tablegateway->select(array('id' => $id));
```

If older approach is not suggested any more or Newer approach is just one more way to build things.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: My question is that As Zend have changed lot of things in Tutorial from 2.0 to 2.2. So If using newer approach in Forms/Models is suggested (If yes, then what are advantages comparison to 2.0 one ) or it just another way to work, I am free to choose what suits me.